# fitbit API HTTPS error

Tags: python, https, fitbit

I'm trying to get my heart rate and sleep data through fitbit API, i'm using this:
https://github.com/orcasgit/python-fitbit

in order to connect to the server and get the access and refresh tokens (i use gather_kays_oauth2 to get the tokens).

And when i'm conecting in HTTP I do manage to get the sleep data, but when i'm trying to get the HR like that:

```
client.time_series("https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/activities/heart/date/today/1d.json", period="1d")
```

I get this error:

HTTPBadRequest: this request must use the HTTPS protocol

And for some reason i can't connect in HTTPS - when i do try it, the browser pops up an ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR even before the FITBIT Authorization Page.

i tried to follow and fix any settings that may cause the browser to fail, but they're all good and the error still pops up.

I've tried to change the callback URL, i searched for other fitbit OAUTH2 connection guides, but i only manage to connect in HTTP and not HTTPS

Does anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: Could you include some code please? A [minimal, complete and verfiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be smashing! Otherwise it is hard to know where you're stuck.

Comment: @OliverBaumann thanks! i've added some details, i hope it helps

Comment: what happened with the https request error "this request must use the HTTPS protocol"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be `client.time_series('activities/heart', period='1d')` to get heart rate.

For the first parameter resource, it doesn't need the resource URL, but it asks you to put one of these: activities, body, foods, heart, sleep.

Here is the link of source code from `python-fitbit`:

http://python-fitbit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/fitbit/api.html#Fitbit.time_series

Added:

If you want to get the full heart rate data per minute (["activities-heart-intraday"] dataset), try `client.intraday_time_series('activities/heart')`. It will return data with the one-minute/one-second detail.

Comment: when i try it i get:

HTTPBadRequest: Invalid time series resource path: /heart

same for all the other options

Comment: for: `client.time_series('activities/heart', period='1d')` i get a valid dictionary, but the full HR data- per minute (the ["activities-heart-intrada"] "dataset") is empty

Comment: Did you check whether there is data in your fitbit? Or did you try client.time_series(‘activities/heart’, period=‘1m’) to get the full HR data per minute?

Comment: there's definitely data, and i do get the max/min/avg heart rate values, but not the one-minute/one-second detail (and 1m gives back all the summarized values one month back, still no detailed values)

Comment: @shachar10 Then, try client.intraday_time_series(‘activities/heart’).  http://python-fitbit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#fitbit.Fitbit.intraday_time_series

Comment: @shachar10, maybe consider putting the `client.intraday_time_series()` snippet in your original answer? That way, other people with the same issue don't have to browse the comments for the "real" solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've worked out the HTTPS issue in relation to my need. It was because I sent a request to.

`https://api.fitbit.com//1/user/-/activities/recent.json`

I removed the additional forward slash after .com and it worked

`https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/activities/recent.json`

However, this is not the same issue you had which returned the same message for me `this request must use the HTTPS protocol`.

Which would suggest that any unhandled errors due to malformed requests to Fitbit return this same error. Rather than one that gives you a little more clue as to what just happened.